# Обрыв при выдаче страницы

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi

Есть веб-сервер с apache и PHP. PHP запущен как fastcgi.

Появилась проблема: один из скриптов время от времени обрывается при исполнении и выдаче текста страницы.

Т.е. обновляешь страницу - грузится все нормально, вплоть до тега `</html>`. При следующем обновлении выводится только часть страницы. Примерно 2/3 части.

Генерация страницы занимает примерно 5 секунд.

Этот же скрипт, но с другими параметрами (время генерации - от 2.5 до 3 секунд) отрабатывает без подобных проблем.

В PHP time_limit стоит стандартный, 30 секунд. По памяти тоже все нормально. В логах PHP ошибок нет.

Не совсем понимаю, что еще проверить. Может, кто-то сталкивался с аналогичной проблемой или просто сможет подсказать, на что обратить внимание?

UPDATE:

Следующий скрипт отрабатывает без проблем и всегда

```
<?php
 for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
  echo("STEP: " . $i . "\n");
  sleep(1);
 }
```

Выводятся записи от STEP: 0 до STEP: 19

Comment: Если хостинг не Ваш, то хостер может убивать процессы по таймауту. И ему глубоко ... неинтересен Ваш `php.ini`.

Comment: Значение time_limit не из конфига, а из вывода phpinfo()

Comment: Похоже, что хостинг всё-таки не Ваш... `phpinfo` не выдаст ограничений, накладываемых на уровне ОС.

Comment: @kff хостинг не мой. Но натурный эксперимент показал что срипты дольше 20 секунд работают без проблем. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: А попробуйте вместо `sleep` выполнять бессмысленную работу, ***загружающую процессор***. Интересно, через сколько его прибьют? Подозреваю, что как раз и будет 5 секунд.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в настройках сервера. Выяснилось что там еще стоил кешируюший nginx. Вот он и оказался виновником проблемы - у процесса nginx не хватало прав на запись в папку кеша. После настроек прав все стало работать как часы.